# Is it possible to get Maven to test compile JSP's?

Tags: jsp, maven-2, maven

I just converted one of our web projects from NetBeans ANT to Maven 2 in order to ease our dependency management, this has proved brilliant, however I didn't realise that Maven will not test compile the JSP's by default.

I found [the JSPC maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jspc-maven-plugin/) which does the compiling, but I don't actually want the artefacts that it creates. I did think about using it with the ant task plugin to throw the built JSP's away but wanted to hear if anyone else has another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put this plugin call to separate maven profile - and call it when you need- on Hudson before deploy to test server -for example... And just *mvn clean* after...

Comment: Great idea, it's a workaround, but the good part of the word workaround is the first four letters :) It'll 'work'. It'd still be brilliant if there were an option to not save the built binaries :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to support maven-war-overlays, I'm getting errors saying that it cannot find a file that belongs in my overlaid WAR - any ideas?

Comment: Apparently this question answers mine: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/jsp-precompile-with-war-overlay-td81604.html